# Java ProcessBuilder cant run simple script

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, processbuilder

I have `test.sh` which calls some program and that program output some lines.

My need is to capture only last line of output

so if I do simple

```
bash test.sh | tail -n 1  ========> Command 1
```

then I get error `"Do you want output to go to | or to tail"`

so to fix above problem, I do

```
(bash test.sh) | tail -n 1   =======> Command 2
```

and then I get simple 1 line of log. So far so good.

Now I need to call above command via java program, so I pass '(' as first argument to `ProcessBuilder` but it complains that it cant understand '(' as first argument.

How can I pass `Command 2` to `ProcessBuilder` to get last line of log.

I am not very familiar with bash and linux so please pardon my ignorance. I even dont know why I am getting error for `command 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are now using Java, you could use the "write once run everywhere" aspect of it. Write a program that opens a file, reads its lines, and get the last one. It will work for any platform.

A good class for it is the [BuffedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Answer (score 0):

To get the last line in the file use-

```
$tail -1 filename.dat
```

A quick demo

```
$ cat filename.dat
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
End Line
$ tail -1 filename.dat
End Line
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's `ProcessBuilder` (and consequently, the `Runtime.exec` methods) don't support piping (`|`), redirection (`>`), and running multiple commands (`&`). Instead, you should create a separate script that calls your bash script and pipes it to tail:

```
#!/bin/sh
#tailLog.sh
bash test.sh | tail -n 1
```

Then in Java:

```
processBuilder.command("tailLog.sh");
```

Remember that `|` and other shell tokens are specific to the *shell*, so Java won't recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some reordering here to make this easier.

- No need to use the tail command as you can capture the last when reading the ProcessBuilder output.
- To ensure that your script runs when your Java app call it, ensure that `#!/bin/bash` appears as the first line in your script. Also make sure it is executable.

Here is a code adapted from an existing app which will capture the last line.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("test.sh");
Process process = builder.start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
String lastLine = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
if (line != null) {
   lastLine = line;
}
}

System.out.println(lastLine);
```

Comment: I could do that and that is obvious answer but if program is outputting thousands of line then it is not very useful. I dont want to go through all lines :(

Comment: Does tail command actually do the same thing? Does it have internal buffer and read all lines one by one ? If it does then may be I could justify usage of above pattern.

Comment: You could place your command with tail inside another script :)

Comment: @user1631667 I'd have to actually look (I'm just guessing here) but it probably seeks to the end of the file and works backwards, building a string until it reaches the appropriate number of lines. This is possible in Java, btw, using [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and the `seek` method.